# Visual Studio Error 1297 Device does not install on any devices, use primitive driver if intended

Tags: windows, visual-studio, kernel

My problem is visual studio 2019 kernel mode 1297 failed (Device driver does not install on any devices, use primitive driver if this is intended). I have all of spectre library but take in this fault, please help me.

I have all spectre library, but not worked